# Retrieve quota for Microsoft Azure App Service Storage

Tags: azure, metrics, quota, azure-appservice

How to retrieve an Azure App Service storage capacity?

The "Quotas" menu shows me 52% "File system storage" is used, but I am not able to either any of this

- find any condition in alert rule
- api to retrieve this metric
- C# code, to find the limit by code

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftwebsites?

Comment: Many thanks for the information, this was quite helpful. Unfortunately I am unable to locate neither any Rest API or any metric which can give me the current file system capacity, looking for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure App Service Plan's "List Usage" API works with an oAuth2.0 Rest API which can be tried out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/listusages

**Security**: Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow
Type: oauth2
Flow: implicit
Authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize

**Details are**:
URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms//usages?api-version=2019-08-01

**Filters can be added with ODATA syntax**:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms//usages?$filter=name.value eq 'FileSystemStorage'&api-version=2019-08-01

[image]

Comment: For my curiosity, I asked a question about the difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766959/why-does-filesystemusage-metric-for-microsoft-web-sites-always-return-zero. My answer is only correct if the App Service is hosted in an App Service Environment. I will delete my answer now :).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. These metrics only works for App Services