# Why does "FileSystemUsage" metric for "Microsoft.Web/sites" always return zero?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, metrics, azure-monitoring

While answering [Retrieve quota for Microsoft Azure App Service Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763214/retrieve-quota-for-microsoft-azure-app-service-storage), I stumbled upon the `FileSystemUsage` metric for `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource type. As per the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftwebsites), this metric should return `Percentage of filesystem quota consumed by the app.`.

However when I execute [`Metrics - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) REST API operation (and also in the Metrics blade in Azure Portal) for my web app, the value is always returned as zero. I checked it against a number of web apps in my Azure Subscriptions and for all of them the result was zero. I am curious to know the reason for that.

In contrast, if I execute [`App Service Plans - List Usages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/listusages) REST API operation, it returns me the correct value. For example, if my App Service Plan is S2, I get following response back:

```
{
  "unit": "Bytes",
  "nextResetTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
  "currentValue": 815899648,
  "limit": 536870912000,//500 GB (50 GB/instance x max 10 instances)
  "name": {
    "value": "FileSystemStorage",
    "localizedValue": "File System Storage"
  }
},
```

Did I misunderstand `FileSystemUsage` for Web Apps? Would appreciate if someone can explain the purpose of this metric? If it is indeed what is documented, then why the API is returning zero value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the default behavior, please check this doc [Understand metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-metrics):

> Note
>
> File System Usage is a new metric being rolled out globally, no data
> is expected unless your app is hosted in an App Service Environment.

So currently this metric `File System Usage` should only be working on [ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro).